# can't get rails model name to show in another model's show.html.haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I've got two associated models: softballteam and softballdivision. For creating a New Team, I've got a Name and a select dropdown for the Division. The select field is correctly showing all the Divisions, but it doesn't appear to be saving the selection. When I go back to the Edit page, the select dropdown still shows the first option, and I can't get the Division name to show up in the Team's Show page. I'm using Mongoid, in case that matters.

Here are my models.

```
class Softballdivision
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  validates_presence_of :name

  has_many :softballteams
end

class Softballteam
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  validates_presence_of :name

  belongs_to :softballdivision
end
```

And my form:

```
= form_for @softballteam do |f|
  # error message deleted for brevity

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name

  .field
    = collection_select(:softballdivision, :name, Softballdivision.all, :id, :name)

  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Here is the Team Show page:

```
%p
  %b Name:
  = @softballteam.name
  %br
  %b Division:
  = @softballdivision.name

# links deleted for brevity
```

I feel like I'm inches away and just missing something easy.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks,
Charlie Magee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, in your form it should be:

```
= collection_select(:softballteam, :softballdivision_id, Softballdivision.all, :id, :name)
```

And in your show:

```
= @softballteam.softballdivision.name
```

Comment: Perfect! It makes perfect sense, now that I see it.